# Trigger JMeter tests on a remote system via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

how can we tell Jenkins to download and run JMeter tests on a remote system rather than from the Jenkins server itself?
My requirement is to create a job in Jenkins to download the latest code from a repo to another system where JMeter is installed and run the JMeter tests on that remote system rather than from Jenkins server itself? I can trigger the tests from Jenkins server itself but unable to connect to remote server and download/trigger the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get familiarized with the concept of Jenkins [Distributed Builds](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds), it's enough to [start Jenkins agent proces](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Distributed+builds#Distributedbuilds-Differentwaysofstartingagents) on the "remote system" and bind your job to execute on that agent instead of Jenkins master.

With regards to tracking changes in the remote repo check out [Generic Webhook Trigger](https://plugins.jenkins.io/generic-webhook-trigger/) and  [How to Integrate Your GitHub Repository to Your Jenkins Project](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-integrate-your-github-repository-to-your-jenkins-project) articles